# Calling MPI_Comm_Split function

Tags: fortran, mpi, communicator

My question is probably stupid but still I'm gonna ask it to be sure !

**Question :** Do you expect the two codes below to work the same using MPI_Comm_Split to build 1 sub-communicator ? (for example, let's say I'm running the code with 6 procs with a rank between 0 and 5)

**NB :** The code is in fortran 90 with intel compiler 2019 and I use Mpich for the Mpi.

**CODE 1**

```
call Mpi_Init(ierror)
call Mpi_Comm_Rank(mpi_comm_world,rank,ierror)

if (rank > 2) then
    call Mpi_Comm_Split(mpi_comm_world,0,rank,new_comm,ierror)
else
    call Mpi_Comm_Split(mpi_comm_world,mpi_undefined,rank,new_comm,ierror)
endif
```

**CODE 2**

```
call Mpi_Init(ierror)
call Mpi_Comm_Rank(mpi_comm_world,rank,ierror)

if (rank > 2) then
    color = 0
else
    color = mpi_undefined
endif

call Mpi_Comm_Split(mpi_comm_world,color,rank,new_comm,ierror)
```

The Mpi_Comm_Split is not called the same way in the 2 codes but to me, it should behave the same but I'm not sure... I read that Mpi_Comm_Split has to be invoked at the same line but how procs can know that the call of Mpi_Comm_Split is done at a one line or another one (it doesn't make anysense to me) ?!

**NB :** With Mpich and intel fortran, I tested it and both implentation of the communicator splitting works, but I'm afraid of the behavior of different Mpi compilers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you declared `color` correctly, both codes are equivalent.

`MPI_Comm_split()` is a collective operation, and hence must be invoked by all the ranks of the parent communicator. That does **not** mandate the call has to be performed by the same line of code.

Comment: Yes of course, I haven't showed the variables statements in order to get a shorter and more readable message and to focus on my "Mpi_Comm_Split" question !
And thank's for the answer ! It seemed really weird to me that the "call Mpi_Comm_Split" had to be at the same line yet I wasn't 100% sure !